# Editing the form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a form in my app where I can take details of a suer. Now I want to create a form which can allow me to edit a form.

My urls.py:

```
url(r'^home/editform/(?P<userpk>[^/]+)/$', 'lexuseditform', name='lexuseditform'),)
```

My view.py:

```
@login_required                              
def lexuseditform(request,userpk):
    if int(userpk) != request.user.pk:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
else:
    form = AdultForm()
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = AdultForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
          form.save()
          redirect_url = reverse('lexus/lexusedited.html')
          return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url) # Redirect after POST
    else:
       form = AdultForm() # An unbound form

return render('lexus/lexuseditform.html', {'form': form})
```

My models.py:

```
class AdultForm(ModelForm):
    """
    Edit Profile Information
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Adult
        fields = ('user', 'email','fullname','created')
```

But i am getting an error msg:
      No ReverseMatch: Reverse for 'lexuseditform' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Can't seem to solve this error. Need some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you POST handling, reverse should be passed URL name not the pattern. So correct it whatever name you have given to that url.

```
redirect_url = reverse('lexus/lexusedited.html') <----- Incorrect.
```

If your urlname is 'lexusedited'

```
redirect_url = reverse('lexusedited')
```

Tip: you can directly do:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('lexusedited'))
```